# How do I open this sidelight door?

Tags: doors

The house that I am in contract on has a sidelight door like this
[image: Sidelight door]

How do I open it? I tried opening the latch near the bottom and pushing it outwards. It made a little sound like it was opening, but didn't actually open. I have a feeling there should be some sort of a crank that's missing on the gear-like thing in the middle. Is that it?

Comment: It may have a 3 point locking mechanism (top bottom and middle)    I have those on my house and they have been a total PITA over the last 15 years.  I have to somehow get them to open, disassemble the side of the door, clean up everything an re-oil and reassemble.  They are Pella brands and while other manufactures have also made them, I trusted Pella.   Nobody makes them anymore.   ....supposedly more secure, but a maintenance nightmare.    You or may not have there types of doors, so take my comment with a few grains of salt!

Comment: You could ask the previous owner

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a casement window. If so, then yes, to operate it you throw the lever to release the catch that holds it tightly sealed, then turn the crank to operate the mechanism.

Ask the seller where that crank handle might be, or buy a replacement.

Comment: There’s also usually a plastic cover to hide the mechanism… once you’ve opened it, you might discover a manufacturer name.

Comment: Thanks! I will ask the seller where the crank is.